# rails 3.1, devise gem, :timeoutable is not working, why?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, devise

I am trying to use the auto signout feature,

here is my model:

```
class Student < ActiveRecord::Base

  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :timeoutable

  def timeout
      3.seconds
  end
end
```

here is the routes.rb:

```
  devise_for :students do get '/students/sign_out' => 'students/sessions#destroy' end
```

I sign-in, then I wait 5 seconds, at this time, student session should be expired, but, if vavigating to any other
protected page is not redirecting back to login form, meaning that the session is still active.

Is there something I am missing ?? what shall I check ?

Thanks,
hopewise

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is an incorrect information on devise wiki. The correct method is `timeout_in`.

I've fixed the wiki page https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Add-timeout_in-value-dynamically.

Comment: I have upgraded to Devise 1.5.2, but, the auto logout is still not working, what shall I check now ??

I added this to the student model:

  def timeout_in
      2.seconds
  end

  def timeout
      2.seconds
  end

but, still not working, I tried to put a breakpoint into the above methods, using RubyMine, but, they were never reached.

any idea please ?

Comment: I have uploaded an example here:

https://github.com/rodrigoflores/Testing-Timeout.

Check https://github.com/rodrigoflores/Testing-Timeout/blob/master/app/models/user.rb and the development log says that the timeout is working https://github.com/rodrigoflores/Testing-Timeout/blob/master/log/development.log#L138

Comment: I found the solution,
the config.timeout_in was commented at the file devise.rb at config/initializers folder

I thought that adding :timeoutable is all what I have to do, I think devise.rb at config/initializers should be added to the documentation beside talking about :timeoutable, it will be helpful for RoR newbies like me!

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution,
the config.timeout_in was commented at the file devise.rb at config/initializers folder

I thought that adding :timeoutable is all what I have to do, I think devise.rb at config/initializers should be added to the documentation beside talking about :timeoutable, it will be helpful for RoR newbies.

Comment: Not sure if this is the answer. 

On my testing app (<https://github.com/rodrigoflores/Testing-Timeout/blob/master/config/initializers/devise.rb>), I did not touch this file and everything worked. But I'm glad that your problem is solved :).